# ssh and reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh

I have a server with only one public IP where access is restricted to 443 port only.
I have configured an apache reverse proxy for access to https web pages.
I have configured https://one.example.com for web site #1 and https://two.example.com for web site #2.
I want to allow the command ssh three.example.com for a ssh session. How can I do this?

Comment: Apache is not a suitable proxy for SSH.

Answer (score 2):

SSH cannot be reverse proxied like that. Look at configuring a VPN server and gaining access to hosts on your internal network via the VPN.

For example: [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) is commonly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Putty allows you to configure HTTP Proxy:

[image]

Perhaps you can try to also configure apache as a normal proxy onlly allowing to connect to you host on port 22.

Answer (score 0):

You need a proxy in front of apache in order to discriminate `SSH` and `HTTPS` flux, which are conceptually totally different (`SSH` pops its banner and waits for answer, `HTTPS` listens for client initiative).

[sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) is what you are looking for. It binds on port 443 and redirect `SSH` traffic to localhost:22 and `HTTPS` traffic to localhost:443 (or whatever IP you configure it). Options to be set:

```
OPTIONS="--user nobody \
    --pidfile $PIDFILE \
    -p  $Public_IP_Address_Here:443 \
    --ssl 127.0.0.1:443 \
    --ssh 127.0.0.1:22"
```